# How to assign page layout for different records in Account object?

Tags: page-layout

i have:

1. **Account** Object, and custom fields are: **isTeacher__c**(boolean), **isStudent__c**(boolean)
2. 2 page layout are: **teacher_layout**, **student_layout**

Q: How can i assign **teacher_layout** for record which is **isTeacher__c** = true, student do too
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a Record Type and Page Layout for this purpose. [Here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-knowledge-setup-and-customization/configure-page-layouts-and-record-types) is a Trailhead on how to assign record types and page layouts.

Comment: Good thank u . . . .